# Transition Between Animations (NLA)

Tags: animation

I'm trying to create a smooth transition between two animations (using the blend in/out feature in the NLA). However, after performing the first animation, my armature does a bunch of flips and weird rotations before reaching the starting point for the 2nd animation. I don't understand why this is happening or how to fix it. ** How do I perform a smooth looking transition between two animations? ** [image]

Comment: Don't know whether [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pri8Dof7HWI) about combining Mixamo animations in Blender helps?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i'm still having trouble. I followed the video but the animations are facing different directions still. When I rotate the empty, both actions rotate.

Comment: I'm afraid I've not done much with the NLA editor so far so someone with more experience may be able to help.

Comment: hello, maybe share your file (keep it as simple as possible): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my bvh files as I can get a good blend with other mixamo animations. @moonboots have you ever seen that behavior before, where the armature rotates/does flips while blending two animations?

Comment: I don't know, please share your file